# Set a visual focus on a element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've seen some pages with a cool visual focus on elements for example a div:
[alt text http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3007/32303100.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3007/32303100.png)

The white box is a div and the rest of the page is dimmed out.
Are there jQuery plugins for that effekt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery Spotlight](http://www.gilbertpellegrom.co.uk/demo/jquery-spotlight/)